# Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'Service.ServiceManager'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, automapper

I'm receiving the following error after attempting to implement Identity into an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Services.Contracts.IServiceManager Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Service.ServiceManager': Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'Service.ServiceManager'.)'
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'AutoMapper.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate
> 'Service.ServiceManager'.

I'm really not sure why I'm running into this issue. Any help or input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an update:

I've checked the version of AutoMapper I'm using in my Service Layer:

AutoMapper.Exteions.Microsoft.DepdencyInjection v. 7.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this one took some time. But here was the issue:

ServiceManager and AuthenticationService both had using statements for Automapper.Configuration. I replaced them with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and the issue was resolved.